# Use API instead of sql query for authenticating users in openfire

Tags: openfire

> Is it possible to use API instead of following sql query for user authentication in openfire properties:
>   jdbcAuthProvider.passwordSQL:   **SELECT username FROM
>   chat_authentication WHERE username=?**

Basically, the chat_authentication table in our mysql database is not functioning properly and hence some users' entries are not there in the table. So I want to hit the API(which has very low failure rate) directly. How can I do that in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own class to substitute `DefaultAuthProvider.class` of Openfire.

Can looks like:

```
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthProvider
public class MyAuthProvider implements AuthProvider
```

and implements correctly all the methods.

As alternative you can extends OF's `DefaultAuthProvider` and override all the methods

- public void authenticate(String username, String password) throws UnauthorizedException
- public void authenticate(String username, String token, String digest) throws UnauthorizedException
- getPassword(String)
- public boolean checkPassword(String username, String testPassword) throws UserNotFoundException
- public void setPassword(String username, String password).

Finally, make a jar of your class, deploy it in `openfireDirectory/lib` and change the value of property

```
provider.auth.className
```

with your MyAuthProvider fullname.
You can do it

- by Admin Console Panel -> Server -> System Property
- or by database updating OfProperty table.

After that, you'll must shut down and start Openfire.

Comment: But for that: 1. I'll have to understand the whole JDBCAuthProvider class for proper understanding. 2. what about usercreation method in JDBCAuth?

Comment: this can be another way, more complex. Just check on source code of Openfire, it's really long to explain, but in source code there are a lot of comments and a lof of properties to use (jdbcAuthProvider.xyz)